# simulate enter key in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a playbook to run the mysql_secure_installation command.

This command ask several questions.  I am using pexpect, but not sure how to simulate an "enter"
The first question it asks is "enter a root password" I dont want to enter a root password.  The sql server will only be local.

```
- name: "Secure MariaDB"
  expect:
    command: /bin/mysql_secure_installation
    responses:
      Question:
        - ''          #I want to have ansible hit enter
        - 'n'         # Type n
        - 'y'         # Type y
        - 'y'         # Type y
        - 'y'         # Type y
        - 'y'         # Type y
```

I have tried with a '', the command `/bin/bash -c "echo"` and even just a blank line and I keep getting the response below.

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/mysql_secure_installation", "delta": "0:00:30.128184", "end": "2018-08-29 18:54:30.983455", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-08-29 18:54:00.855271", "stdout": "\r\nNOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB\r\n      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!\r\n\r\nIn order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current\r\npassword for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and\r\nyou haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,\r\nso you should just press enter here.\r\n\r\nEnter current password for root (enter for none): ", "stdout_lines": ["", "NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB", "      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!", "", "In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current", "password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and", "you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,", "so you should just press enter here.", "", "Enter current password for root (enter for none): "]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working.  As it turns out some of the stuff was being recoginzed as regex special characters.

```
- name: "Secure MariaDB"
  expect:
    command: /bin/mysql_secure_installation
    responses:
      'Enter current password for root \(enter for none\): ': ''
      'Set root password\? \[Y\/n\] ': 'n'
      'Remove anonymous users\? \[Y\/n\] ': 'y'
      'Disallow root login remotely\? \[Y\/n\] ': 'y'
      'Remove test database and access to it\? \[Y\/n\] ': 'y'
      'Reload privilege tables now\? \[Y\/n\] ': 'y'
    echo: yes
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `no_log: yes` if you don't want your password to be logged

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/iK29xd4QeaE/p8P4tU1lCgAJ) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742347/10287595), you need only specify an empty string; Ansible will be automatically follow it with "enter".

If that doesn't work, there is another suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220698/10287595) to use `/bin/bash -c "echo"` for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) `expect` is flagged as preview so may change, and the module is very simple. It may be more sensible to use an `expect` script; this would allow the detection of each question and the ability to fail out should the questions change in some new version of `mysql_secure_installation` (or to fail out if someone snuck in and put a password on the `root` mysql account, or ...)

This is, however, more work as an `expect` package may need to be installed and the script copied to the system, details will vary depending on the ports or package system involved and where exactly local scripts get installed (hopefully to somewhere untrusted local users cannot read or run them...)

```
- name: install packages for centos
  yum: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - expect
    ...
- name: copy script
  copy: src=root/bin/do-setup-mysql dest=/root/bin/do-setup-mysql ...
- name: initial setup of mysql
  command: /root/bin/do-setup-mysql
  args:
    creates: /todofixme
```

And then the script `do-setup-mysql` might start along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
proc die {msg} { puts stderr $msg; exit 1 }
#log_file /root/do-setup-mysql.log
spawn -noecho mysql_secure_installation
expect "Enter current password for root"
send "\r"
expect {
    timeout { die "timeout before response" }
    "Access denied" { die "root password already set" }
    "Setting the root password" {}
}
expect "Change the root password"
send "n\r"
...
```

And so forth for the remainder of the questions. The script must create `/todofixme`, or that file could instead be something known created by `mysql_secure_installation` so that the initial setup does not run each and every ansible run.